# Sequelize Insert Relation Based on Foreign Column

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have the following tables in MySQL.

---

**Author's table**

```
| id | uuid | name |
|----|------|------|
| 1  | abc  | Bob  |
| 2  | xyz  | Will |
```

**Book's table**

```
| id | title | timestamp | author |
|----|-------|-----------|--------|
| 1  | Hello | 124       | 2      |
| 2  | World | 175       | 1      |
```

As you can see, `author` is a foreign key for the `Author.id` column.

---

Then I have the following code in my application.

```
const book = await models.Book.create({
    title: "Space",
    timestamp: 562,
    author: "xyz",
});
```

Of course this is breaking because the `author` doesn't link to the author's `id` but to the `uuid` column.

In Sequelize how can I achieve this? Where the foreign key relates to `id` but we insert that foreign key using `uuid`.

Is there a way to update my `.create` function call to allow for this? I know I can simply do a query before inserting, but that loses efficiency.  So that is why I'm trying to achieve it this way.

Comment: instead of `author`, try `author_id` and point to the author PK

Comment: @mcranston18 So inside of my `.create` call change `author: "xyz"` to `author_id: 2`? If so, I don't have access to the number 2 at this point in my application. I can't manually hard code that because I'm getting it from another source where I only have access to that `uuid`.

Comment: yes the syntax is right. So can't you make a request for the author ID before you create the book?

Comment: @mcranston18 I mean I could query the database, get the id where the uuid equals what I have, then create it. But that seems SUPER inefficient. Normally with SQL you can do most of that in one command, instead of having to do two commands. Maybe I'm wrong and it's impossible to achieve it the way I want to.

Comment: fwiw, a db look up to get a UUID doesn't seem too inefficient to me, but I don't know the specifics of your app. Anyway w Sequelize, you'll need to fetch the `author_id` before hand if you're planning on associating it with the book.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused. Which is the primary key- the `id` or `uuid` field? Is there a reason to have both?

Comment: @mcranston18 Primary is `id`. Probably not a reason to have both. `id` is just the default in MySQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168006/discussion-between-mcranston18-and-charlie-fish).